Why package-delete is not persistent and package keeps getting reinstalled on restart?
I keep seeing the following warning each time I open Magit in Emacs
Emergency (emacsql): Uninstall the `git-commit' package.

The "git-commit.el" library is no longer distributed as a separate
package.  It is now distributed as part of the `magit' package.

The `git-commit' package now does nothing but display this warning.
If it is located earlier on the `load-path' than `magit' is, then that
prevents the proper "git-commit.el" libraries from `magit' from being
loaded.

Please uninstalling `git-commit' and then restart Emacs.

Executing (package-delete 'git-commit) does the job temporarily until you restart Emacs where it is reinstalled again.
What might be a reliable fix for it?

Upgrading magit package to most recent version fixed the issue for me.
Relevant Github issue - https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/16555
